# Is using the Swift REPL for my answer valid?

Tags: discussion, policy

This is a very strange hack that I came across the other day. In the Swift REPL, if I create an instance of any type (say for example, a String), it automatically gets assigned to a variable in the same way an argument to a closure is. The name used is `$R{n}`. Here is an example:

[image]

However, *this only works in the REPL*. So I can I use this hack in a Swift answer if I specify that you have to run it like this:

`cat file.swift | swift`

Note that you do get extra output in the form of the blue output in the REPL.

Comment: This belongs on our meta site, and I have voted to migrate.

Comment: I think yes, because Mathematica REPL is valid. (although that is (probably) the default way to run MMA). MMA "last output" is even shorter, `%`.

Comment: You can, if your language is "Swift REPL", not "Swift". Also, might want to migrate this to meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, but Swift and Swift REPL are different.

Yes, you are allowed to use all the features of REPL Swift (Terminal Swift), as long as you specify that your language is **Swift REPL**, not **Swift**. For example, your header should **not look** like this:

```
#Swift, X bytes
```

Instead, it should be:

```
#Swift REPL, X bytes
```

The same applies to all languages with a REPL version, such as **Python** and **Python REPL.**

---

If you want to keep it in **Swift**, you may use your code from the REPL version, and specify that your program must be ran with:

```
cat file.swift | swift
```

If you include `cat file.swift | swift` in your byte count (i.e. `<program bytes> + X bytes` (for `cat file.swift | swift`))